# Same URL endpoint in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Is it possible to achieve this in Razor Pages:

`Product.cshtml` `@page "/{url_product}"` – retrieve url friendly from database / Product table

`Category.cshtml` `@page "/{url_category}"` – retrieve url friendly from database / Category table

I want to achieve this:

```
www.domain.com/url-friendly-product

www.domain.com/url-friendly-category
```

I tried constraint and it is working, but i have to every request match url from database from both table, and i am afraid about application performance.

Is it possible to do it some other way?

Comment: Normally you should only worry about dealing with application performance issues if you are actually experiencing them. It is common to run multiple queries against a database during a single request. Running the same query against 2 tables might or might not cause issues in exactly the same way that running a single query might or might not, based on a lot of factors including but not limited to database system in use, schema design, optimisations e.g indexes etc, etc.

Comment: Why not change `@page "/{url_product}"` to `@page "product/{url_product}"`?Then you only need to match the url for one time and it could improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

I have this custom constraint and if will be in database 10 000 product for every request, I think is not good.

Is some other options to achieve this? Or is it only this way to do it?

```
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
    public ProductConstraint(IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, string routeKey, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (_cache.Get("URLProductListCache") == null)
        {
            var cacheEntry = _cache.CreateEntry("URLProductListCache");
            var _context = (ApplicationDbContext)httpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ApplicationDbContext));
            var url = _context.Product.AsNoTracking().Select(c => c.URL).ToList();
            cacheEntry.SetValue(url);
            cacheEntry.Dispose();

            return url.Contains(values[routeKey]?.ToString().ToLowerInvariant());
        }
        else
        {
            var url = _cache.Get("URLProductListCache") as List<string>;
            return url.Contains(values[routeKey]?.ToString().ToLowerInvariant());
        }
    }
```